# can someone help to formulate the correct random effects part for nlme and lm4

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

below is a dataset (selection) with 4 persons (person), each measured 5 times (test) in 5 different situations (situation) for a certain response (value).
 I want the alternative of the linear model on the first test in both nlme and lme4 but do not succeed to end up with 4 DF for my main effect, so I can't specify the pseudoreplication in a correct way.
 Can someone complete the random parts of the formula's (and explain?).
Many thanks

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
modellm <- with(selection,lm(value~situation,subset=(test==1)))
modelnlme <- lme(value~situation, random=~1|test/person,selection)
modellme4 <- lmer(value~situation+(1|person)+(1|test),data=selection)

selection <- structure(list(person = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), situation = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), value = c(22.0843801261104, 
24.1576517738957, 19.7175043298103, 19.3379945973054, 11.9902471394439, 
18.402205450866, 25.3315005334281, 18.5612719573244, 18.1463069173919, 
16.1571385525506, 23.6263822037244, 23.9416178172244, 21.5898399097672, 
18.1347706836603, 11.3776067348062, 18.2147407148914, 23.1460188658659, 
16.1065522484067, 18.9289912294568, 12.1274801617051, 18.7271915605956, 
24.2312704194697, 18.6157269453958, 8.21583899513255, 11.303344890824, 
10.1626719475305, 5.82889849316264, 5.44683258552254, 2.47550678881482, 
10.3189356436874, 12.6236820002119, 8.51782990465832, 3.38596989501193, 
3.75021184501722, 9.20731388236198, 12.7313326479766, 10.1750440136918, 
6.90466380944549, 2.56252076904005, 9.08212767070886, 11.9609889915673, 
5.95600607861904, 5.79284227783921, 2.39236576873504, 10.3236552647387, 
12.2752245699658, 7.7725220554397, 5.74802352009632, 2.94445578599034, 
14.0196385198073, 19.2758939489628, 13.6726490625299, 16.4744373372209, 
10.0558577025887, 13.9850026511262, 15.8321425926674, 14.8605011298239, 
14.6870565037345, 7.4831311820393, 15.9062501625202, 15.5675528463743, 
15.3388101002803, 13.7156403911375, 5.53858786301708, 19.5547168210647, 
16.4712079950265, 16.0329881018502, 15.1356493425604, 9.30795626420621, 
17.44433851116, 12.160468677202, 14.4847862374805, 16.5858910080605, 
7.87580772389727, 19.4516496610715, 14.2702900351105, 26.9430452018599, 
32.4646543611035, 7.55521910513664, 18.5217173694012, 17.1140333113553, 
26.2127876816636, 33.3915197957702, 9.89706748717028, 14.6678506415166, 
17.1293515542169, 28.3421388281864, 27.7471698253481, 9.9172875110497, 
18.2457685943334, 15.5227173593343, 27.7103696976708, 27.1483174336176, 
8.08266237481616, 33.286823819804, 16.8909748042784, 28.937473019979, 
28.123007958056, 6.27290017099772)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA,-99L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want (or if you do). Some questions:

- Are the situations a sample from a larger population of possible situations?
- Ditto for tests?
- What is the question you are trying to answer with the model?

Given your description, I might guess something like this, which allows for a random slope for situation within person and has the correct df I think.

SNIP

---

EDIT: based on your response, it sounds like the model I suggested would be fine. However there are alternatives in terms of how you treat 'test' which might be worth considering...

`{r}
m1 <- lmer(value ~ test + situation + (situation|person), data=selection)
m2 <- lmer(value ~ log(test) + situation + (situation|person), data=selection)
m3 <- lmer(value ~  test * situation + (situation|person), data=selection)
m4 <- lmer(value ~  factor(test) * situation + (1|person), data=selection)`

These models imply different assumptions about any order effects for `test`... either that there will be a linear slope, some kind of log curve (2) that test might interact with situations so you get different slopes for each situation (3) or that you want to treat each presentation as a factor (probably makes less sense).

It's probably worth including the random effect for situation to allow for the possibility that people didn't respond the same to all of the situations... See http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/KeepItMaximalR2.pdf

Comment: The 5 situations are fixed situations, there were no alternatives for these. For the 5 tests: this was just a number to identify a within person and within situation repeat (the tests come from a larger population, we could have done 10 repeats within the same person either in stead of 5). The question I wanted to answer is: does the response value differ between the situations (regardless of the person or the repeat of the test).